# Swiftmailer multiple recipients with different content

Tags: php, html, swiftmailer

I am developing a newsletter emailer, where I have to send thousands of mails with different body content. How can I do this using swiftmailer?
Now my code is:

```
$emails = array('mail1@gmail.com'=>'name1',
        'mail2@gmail.com'=>'name2',
        'mail3@gmail.com'=>'name3',
        'mail4@gmail.com'=>'name4',
        'mail5@gmail.com'=>'name5');

$message = Swift_Message::newInstance('Testing Email')
      ->setFrom(array('mail1@gmail.com' => 'name'))
      ->setTo($emails) //$emails
      ->setReplyTo(array('reply_to@gmail.com' => 'reply'));
    $html = $this->send_model->getEmailContent();
    $body = $html;
      $message->setBody($body, 'text/html')
      ;

    // Send the message
    $result = $mailer->send($message);
```

I want to send all separate mails for all the emails which are in the above array.. with different body content.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: if the body is different for each email, you have to use one instance of `Swift_Message` for each email.